# Combine Yolo V8?

Tags: computer-vision, yolo, yolov8

Let's say I had 3 datasets I wanted to combine to have more data and differentiated data.  Here is some examples :

https://universe.roboflow.com/yolo-project/6_class_final/health

https://universe.roboflow.com/qilu-university-of-technology-wb81s/ship-detection-uyjkr/health

https://universe.roboflow.com/ship-8qmp3/ship-avafs/health

Now I download them as Yolo V8.  However it's a touch unclear what needs to be done to build a custom dataset of all of these.

Obviously I need to synchronize the class names (Military --> Warship, for example).  However is the *only* file that needs to be edited in each the data.yaml file containing the class names?

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll need to remap all of the class IDs also. The easiest way to do this is to upload them into a custom Roboflow project & use [the "Remap Classes" preprocessing step](https://blog.roboflow.com/introducing-class-management/) then re-export in YOLO format.